# the importance of facebook offline_access permission

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

What's the importance of the facebook offline_access permission?

What it is useful for while the application can for example post to the user wall even if he is not logged in (of course after he once allowed access to the application without the offline_access permission).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Facebook PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), you ask for the `offline_access` permission when generating the login link :

```
$args['scope'] = 'offline_access';
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
```

Then you can make API calls with that token :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$facebook->setAccessToken(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN);

$facebookdata = $facebook->api('/me');
```

The `offline_permission` allows you to make API calls with the token, even when the user has logged out.

Hope that helps !

Comment: I gave permission to my app, without the offline_acces, and then I cleared all coockies so I'm logged out, and I tried to post on my wall, with my user id and not /me and it worked, so I really don't understand the real necessity. as the app can post to users walls even after they log out and clear all the coockies, a user id is more than enough.

Comment: It is because your are using the access token of the app (not the one of the user) so you are posting **as the app**, not as the user. If you want to access private data of the user or take actions on his behalf, you will need his token. And if you want to do it when he is not logged in anymore, you will need the `offline_access` permission.

Comment: another question please, my app must have a profile page? and if yes how to hide myself from being the developper? I want it to be anonymous.

Comment: Yes all the apps have a page tha is `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID`. I don't know if you are anonymous when you make an app but you can create a new Facebook account and create your app from this new account.

Comment: but creating multiple accounts is not legal according to facebook TOS

Comment: Really ? I don't know about that. Facebook allows accounts for organizations or website (I mean, not human user) so I guess you can create an account just for your app...

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Permissions:](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

> Enables your app to perform authorized
>   requests on behalf of the user at any
>   time. By default, most access tokens
>   expire after a short time period to
>   ensure applications only make requests
>   on behalf of the user when the are
>   actively using the application. This
>   permission makes the access token
>   returned by our OAuth endpoint
>   long-lived.